# Glossary items stopped linking to the actual word

Tags: latex, glossary

I am currently writting a report and implemented a glossary using the

```tex
\usepackage{glossaries}
```

Everything was working great a few days ago :

- each word that required definition in my text was declared in my glossary and was linked with the `\acrshrt{}` function

For instance :

```tex
\usepackage{glossaries}
\makeglossaries

\section{Example}
bla bla bla \acrshrt{dms} bla bla bla

\newacronym{dms}{DMS}{DMS meaning}
```

which led to :

[image] and [image] (pages and word are clickable and point back to the word and its definition)

However now I have :

[image] and [image]

I geniuenly do not understand why it suddenly stopped working.
I tried removing `\hyperref` and `\url` packages, but no changes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Solution found :

For some very **very** ***VERY*** obscure reasons, loading the `\usepackage{hyperref}` before `\usepackage{glossaries}` worked.

Guess from now on I'll stop ordering my packages in an alphabetical order .. x)